# MPMoviePlayerController not recognizing UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to my MPMoviePlayerController, like this:

```
- (void)playVideo {
    NSString *videoURL = self.post[@"videos"][@"high_resolution"];
    videoURL = [videoURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURL];
    self.videoURL = url;

    self.videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    self.videoController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.videoController.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self.videoController setContentURL:self.videoURL];
    [self.videoController.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, 320, 320)];
    [_sharedImage addSubview:self.videoController.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playy)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.videoController];
    self.playBtn.hidden = YES;
    [self.videoController play];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [_videoController.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    [_videoController pause];
    NSLog(@"Video was tapped");
}

#pragma mark - Gesture Delegate
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

But the MPMoviePlayerController seems not to recognize the tap gesture, and nothing happens when I tap the video. Please explain this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should set disabled interactions like so...

```
self.videoController.userInteractionEnabled = false;
```

Then add your gesture to the superview instead

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing one important line:

```
tap.delegate = self;
```

delegates won't be called if you don't set it

Comment: the OP set self as the gesture recognizer target.  that's enough to get the handleTap: message.

Comment: try to comforms to gesture delegates: @interface yourVC <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>